# Azure DevOps - Unable to Create Var Group using Azure DevOps API and Auth Token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Requirements: We would like to create a Variable Group (along with some variables) in a given Project.

1. Option1: We are able to create a new Variable Group successfully
   when we create a request via PostMan using PAT Token which has FULL access.
2. Option2: Our end goal is to invoke the ADO Rest API in the Web App which uses
   OAuth. When the end user logs in and make a call (pls see the input
   details below) we are getting '401 Un Authorized - The user is not authorized to access this resource.' error. The Web App's application has the Variable Groups manage scope as shown below.
   [image]

TroubleShooting: As part of troubleshooting, for Option1 which uses PAT (with full access) in Postman, we have updated the permissions of the PAT to just have **Create, Read and Manage Var Groups** as shown below.

[image]

Now, even the Option1 is not working after making the PAT to have Custom Defined access.

Are we missing something?

**Postman Details:**

URL: https://dev.azure.com/myorgname/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2

Verb: Post

Headers: Authorization: Basic

Body:

```
 {
"name": "This is ignored",
"description": "This is ignored",
"type": "Vsts",
"variables": {
    "BuildConfiguration": {
        "value": "Release"
    }
    
},
"variableGroupProjectReferences": [
    {
        "name": "VarGroup",
        "description": "The variable group to store the information about the variables using in the Pipeline",
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "#ProjectId#",
            "name": "#ProjectName#"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue with option 1, not only `Read, create, & manage` for `Variable Groups`, even I select `all the scopes` via `Custom defined`, it still does not work.

According to this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-pats-with-policies-for-administrators?view=azure-devops#restrict-creation-of-full-scoped-pats

> **Some of our public APIs are currently unassociated with a PAT scope, and can therefore only be used with “full-scoped” PATs.** Because of this, restricting the creation of full-scoped PATs might block some workflows. We're working to identify and document the affected APIs and eventually associate them with the appropriate scope. For now, these workflows can be unblocked by using the allow list.

I believe this should be the reason for this issue, there may be some additional permissions to create variable groups. For option 2, there may be a similar cause.

So in this case, you may need to use the `Full access` PAT temporarily, as mentioned in the doc `We're working to identify and document the affected APIs and eventually associate them with the appropriate scope.`